# Bytes in an string to bytes

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing an program where you can enter bytes wich you have got from an encoding. When I get the value of this text widget, I got an string including this bytes. For decoding I need this bytes inside the string an datatype bytes. How can I do that? For Example you enter something like this: b'U_\xf8x\x84 \xfd\xa9'. But when you get your value of the text widigt, where it is entered you get this as an string but i ned it as bytes.

```
text = textfeldEingabe.get('1.0', 'end').strip()
text = str(text)
print(text)
text = bytes(text.encode())
print(text)
startEntschluesselung = False
try:
    dEntschluesselung = int(entryPrivaterKey.get())
    nEntschluesselung = int(entryNEntschluesselung.get())
    startEntschluesselung = True
except:
    messagebox.showerror('Eingabefehler', 'Geben Sie für n, Blocklaenge und private Key ganze Zahlen ein')

if startEntschluesselung:
    textEntschluesselt = verschluesseln(text, (dEntschluesselung, nEntschluesselung))
    textfeldAusgabe.config(state='normal')
    textfeldAusgabe.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textfeldAusgabe.insert('1.0', textEntschluesselt)
    textfeldAusgabe.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: `bytes(text)` ?

Comment: I already tryed this but it doesn´t works. You get something like this: b"b'tBvcj\\xfa\\x16\\x94\\x92'" out of this: b'tBvcj\xfa\x16\x94\x92'

Comment: What exactly does it mean to “typ in bytes”?!

Comment: You enter something like this: b'U_\xf8x\x84 \xfd\xa9'

Comment: You want `ast.literal_eval`.